# parsec produce strange errors when trying to handle Maybe as ParseError

Tags: parsing, haskell

If I have this code :

```
import Text.Parsec

ispositive a = if (a<0) then Nothing else (Just a)

f a b = a+b  

parserfrommaybe :: String -> (Maybe c) -> Parsec a b c
parserfrommaybe msg Nothing  = fail msg
parserfrommaybe _ (Just res)  = return res    

(<!>) :: Parsec a b (Maybe c) -> String -> Parsec a b c
(<!>) p1 msg = p1 >>= (parserfrommaybe msg)    

integermaybeparser = (ispositive <$> integer) <!> "negative numbers are not allowed"
testparser = f <$> (integermaybeparser <* whiteSpace) <*> integermaybeparser
```

when I test `testparser` with input like this "-1 3" it gives :

```
Left (line 1, column 4):
unexpected "3"
negative numbers are not allowed
```

I expected it to give error on Column 1 and give the error message without the sentence "unexpected 3" but it seems parsec continued parsing.

Why did this happen ? and how to make parsec give the error message I expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, the cause of is that the first parser gets run and consumes input even when failing.

The solution was to use `lookAhead` like this:

```
(<!>) :: (Monad m,Stream a m t) => ParsecT a b m (Maybe c) -> String -> ParsecT a b m c
(<!>) p1 msg =  ((lookAhead p1) >>= (parserfrommaybe msg)) *> (p1 >>= (parserfrommaybe msg))
```

if `lookAhead p1` returns `Nothing` then the first argument of `*>` would fail without consuming input because of `lookAhead`, now if `lookAhead p1` returns `Just res` then it would succeed again without consuming input and the result would be obtained from the second argument of `*>`.

ofcourse I had to change `parserfrommaybe` type annotation to `(Monad m) => String -> (Maybe c) -> ParsecT a b m c` to satisfy ghc.

Comment: Just to point out, this will be horribly inefficient - `p1` is almost always being parsed twice. The problem is more basic - if a negative integer is not valid, then why parse the negative symbol at all? And if you would like to report negative integers errors specially (so you must parse the negative sign) you should use `parserFail` (and not `ispositive <$> ..` - the `Nothing` doesn't represent an error in the way you think here) when you encounter a negative integer - this will cause an actual parser failure, right after the negative integer. `<?>` can't cause a parser to fail.